# Failed to open/load the window. Dropbox.choose ... should only be called from within a user-triggered event handler such as a tap or click event

Tags: dropbox-api

After switching to API V2 authentication, now the step of launching the Dropbox Chooser is failing with this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to open/load the window. Dropbox.choose and Dropbox.save should only be called from within a user-triggered event handler such as a tap or click event.
at E (https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js:1:9789)
at x (https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js:1:11599)
at Object.Dropbox.choose (https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js:1:11672)
at HTMLImageElement.document.getElementById.onclick (https://client1.qa.mydomain.net/Scripts/Documents.js?v=4.5.0.18023:630:21)
at Object.trigger (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:5679)
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:6138)
at Function.each (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:2715)
at r.fn.init.each (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:1003)
at r.fn.init.trigger (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:6114)
at r.fn.init.r.fn.(anonymous function) [as click] (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:6532)
```

I haven't modified the JS code, I do have this code embedded with my own App's client ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="xxx"></script>
```

And this is the same code that worked for API V1 unchanged which triggered the chooser.

```
document.getElementById("DropBoxImg").onclick = function () {
    Dropbox.choose({
    linkType: "direct",
    multiselect: DocumentModule.MultiSelectBool(),
    success: function (files) {
        DocumentModule.SetJsonFile(JSON.stringify({ files: files }));
        DocumentModule.CloudUploadClick();
        DocumentModule.DisplaySpinner(false);
    },
    cancel: function () {
    },
    extensions: ['.doc', '.docx', '.xls', '.txt', '.html', '.htm', '.tiff', 
        '.tif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.pdf', '.xlsx']
    });
};
```

And the above click event is triggered as follows

```
$('#DropBoxImg').click();
```

All I can think of the difference between the V1 and V2 change now is the way I'm authorizing the user.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Failed-to-open-load-the-window-Dropbox-choose-and-Dropbox-save/m-p/243634#M13612 ]

Comment: Is your `$('#DropBoxImg').click();` being triggered by an actual user tap/click event? If you're calling it without a user event, the browser may block the window.

Comment: By the way, if you're referring to https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js vs https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js, that's actually not the API v1 that's being retired, so you don't need to get this done by 9/28/17. The Chooser is separate from the API.

Comment: I'm calling it without a user interaction, and this was working fine before I started the migration to API V2. And thanks for clarifying the chooser's version isn't related to the API versions. So, like I've said the only code change to the existing code is that the user is authorized with API v2 calls now, and no change is made to the JS code.

Comment: The moment I roll back the authorization code to V1, the chooser shows up. The only difference between the two is with v2 and OAuth2 it requires a callback URL to be configured in the App, and the old parameters that were passed to the callback now are part of the State parameter. This is causing the callback URL to be different so I'm not sure how that can be related to this?

Comment: Regardless of which version of the Dropins library you're using, you should only trigger the Chooser on an actual user click event, otherwise it may be blocked as a popup.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I follow your second comment. Use of OAuth 2, including a redirect URI and state parameter are entirely unrelated to the Chooser, which doesn't use OAuth.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I was missing the Chooser/Saver domain settings, now it the window pops up.